# IronPython Desktop Application Template in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: python, desktop-application, ironpython

I can't seem to find any recent info on this. I have recently downloaded VS 2022 Community. When creating a new project, I'm looking for a template for desktop application to write in Python, but no templates appear. I have downloaded the latest version of IronPython with the hopes to work with that framework yet no templates appear still. I also tried this in VS 2019 Community, but that didn't work either.  What am I missing?